# BigQuery very slow on (seemingly) a very simple query

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-logging

We using GCP logs which being exported into BigQuery using log sink.
We don't have a huge amount of logs but each record seems to be fairly large.

Running a simple query seem to take a lot of time with BigQuery. We wonder is it normal or are we doing anything wrong... And is there anything we can do to make it a bit more practical to analize...

For example, query

```
SELECT 
        FORMAT_DATETIME("%Y-%m-%d  %H:%M:%S", DATETIME(timestamp, "Australia/Melbourne")) as Melb_time, 
        jsonPayload.lg.a, 
        jsonPayload.lg.p
FROM `XXX.webapp_usg_logs.webapp_*`
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
LIMIT 100
```

takes

```
Query complete (44.2 sec elapsed, 35.2 MB processed)
```

Thank you!

Comment: On other database, which support indices, adding an index onto the `timestamp` column would help the query.

Comment: Thanks! But BigQuery doesn't seem to use indexes...

Comment: Querying wildcard tables like this takes a hit on performance. That's because the metadata of every table that it matches in the glob (`*`) needs to be read prior to the query executing. Try reducing the scanned tables or use `_TABLE_SUFFIX` in a `WHERE` clause. See: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-wildcard-tables#best_practices

Comment: Yes, thank you! it's working much faster when I manually specify the date.
Do you know if there is a way to cache the metadata once so it could be used every time afterwards?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding this to your query:

```
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX > FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d',  DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 3 DAY))
```

It will filter to get tables with a `TABLE_SUFFIX` from within the last 3 days only  - instead of having BigQuery look at each table from maybe many years of history.